# select last row of table

Tags: sql-server-2005

How to select last row of table in SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126171/select-the-last-row-in-a-sql-table

Comment: @Raj - I'm willing to give OP some slack on this one. Consider that several of his questions have zero to two answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general like this

```
select top 1 *
from table 
order by SomeColumn desc
```