# ExecuteScalar(); With scope_identity() Generating "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, webforms

I've have a form which accept various data (through textboxes and a checkboxlist) and on the click event they insert all the data into a table and selects the scope_identity then store it in a variable to use it in the insertion of the checkboxlist items using a loop into another table

according to many answers and examples this should work perfectly!..but it gives me this error :

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Line 66:             int NewBrandId = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Here's my linkbutton method code :

```
   protected void lnkbtnUploadAndSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MOODbCenterConnection"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Brands (BrandName, BrandLogo, BrandWebsite, IsBrandVisible) VALUES (@Name, @Logo, @Website, @IsVisible); SELECT scope_identity();", conn);

        comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        comm.Parameters["@Name"].Value = txtbxBrandName.Text;

        comm.Parameters.Add("@Logo", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters["@Logo"].Value = fileuploadLogo.PostedFile.FileName;

        comm.Parameters.Add("@Website", System.Data.SqlDbType.Text);
        comm.Parameters["@Website"].Value = txtbxWebsite.Text;

        comm.Parameters.Add("@IsVisible", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit);
        comm.Parameters["@IsVisible"].Value = chkbxIsPublished.Checked;
        conn.Open();


        int NewBrandId = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar(); 

        conn.Close();

        foreach (ListItem li in chkbxlstCuisines.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand comm2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BrandCuisines (CuisineId, BrandId) VALUES (@CuisineId, @NewBrandId)", conn);

                comm2.Parameters.Add("@CuisineId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                comm2.Parameters["@CuisineId"].Value = li.Value;

                comm2.Parameters.Add("@NewBrandId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                comm2.Parameters["@NewBrandId"].Value = NewBrandId;
                comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit Strangely the query works fine when I run it directly in the sql server express of the visual studio!

**THE Weird Explanation For This Weird Problem**

First Solution by alexb :

> I did it :) My sql server 2008 returns
>   System.Decimal packed into 'object'.
>   Try to use System.Convert.ToInt32
>   instead of cast.

```
Example : int NewBrandId = System.Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
```

Second Solution by me :

> instead of using "SELECT
>   scope_identity();" I used "SELECT
>   BrandId FROM Brands WHERE BrandId =
>   @@Identity;" it gives you even more
>   controlm but I personally prefare the
>   first solution
>
> N.B : "SELECT @@Identity;" would also
>   work just fine

Thanks guys and I hope it help others!

Comment: There are various reasons you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY. Try casting SCOPE_IDENTITY() to INT within your procedure instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What exactly `comm.ExecuteScalar()` returns? 
Maybe it returns `long` or `double` packed into `object`.
can't remember exactly, but seems like I had faced something 1-2 years ago.

Comment: actually it returns int which i think is the right used cast in "(int)comm.ExecuteScalar();" and I also tested this query directly in the sql server and it worked!

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns decimal(38,0), which .net won't let you cast to an int. See @Maccer's suggestion below for an easy change to the proc, otherwise perform the decimal=>int conversion in .net.

Comment: @Rory you should paste this as an answer cause this is (yours) the right answer.

Answer (score 40):

If you can change the SQL, an even easier way would be to

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Comment: The issue is old, but +1 for a another simple possible solution

Answer (score 4):

As Dimi said, Identity is a SQL Numeric (.NET Decimal).  This should work:

```
decimal decimalBrandId = (decimal)comm.ExecuteScalar(); 
int NewBrandId = (int)decimalBrandId;
```

Comment: or `var newBrandID = (int)(decimal)comm.ExecuteScalar();`

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for **SCOPE_IDENTITY()**

```
Return Types

numeric(38,0)
```

So an easy solution would be the following

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT;

/*
   Do your insert stuff here.
*/

SELECT @ReturnValue = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
SELECT @ReturnValue;
```

Answer (score -2):

try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before the insert.

Comment: still the same error! :S
I think alexb's resolution is right but I'm sure my Id data type is INT and I think i provided the right cast plus I saw the code already from this question >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126171/select-the-last-row-in-a-sql-table 
I wonder...! =)

Comment: so then print the type name of the value returned to debug output and see what is it.

Comment: I did it :)  My sql server 2008 returns `System.Decimal` packed into 'object'. Try to use `System.Convert.ToInt32` instead of cast.

Comment: wow alexb, I just gave up and tried to look for some alternative solutions =)..that's odd indeed and weired :S:D

Comment: @alexb- please update your answer so I could mark it as the answer