# How to Retrieve autoincremnt value after inserting 1 record in single query (sql server)

Tags: iphone, sql, sql-server, triggers

I am have two fields in my table:

One is Primary key auto increment value and second is text value.
lets say: xyzId & xyz

So I can easily insert like this

```
insert into abcTable(xyz) Values('34')
```

After performing above query it must insert these information

```
xyzId=1 & xyz=34
```

and for retrieving I can retrieve like this

```
select xyzId from abcTable
```

But for this I have to write down two operation. Cant I retrieve in single/sub query ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [get new SQL record ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590927/get-new-sql-record-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do an insert and a select in a single query.
You can use a Store Procedures to execute the two instructions as an atomic operation or you can build a query in code with the 2 instructions using ';' (semicolon) as a separator betwen instructions.

Anyway, for select identity values in SQL Server you must check `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT`. It's faster and cleaner than a select in the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later you can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to return the auto created id.

Try this:

```
insert into abcTable(xyz)
output inserted.xyzId
values('34')
```